# iOS Swift - Prevent Timer #fire() on #invalidate()

Tags: ios, swift, timer

Given the following code

```
private var myTimer: Timer? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   // start my Timer
   startMyTimer()
   
   // stop timer and restart
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3)) {
      self.myTimer!.fire()
      print("my timer: invalidating \(Date.now.mediumTimeLocalizedDescription)")
      self.myTimer!.invalidate()
      self.myTimer = nil
      self.startMyTimer()
   }
}

private func startMyTimer() {
   myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: true) { timer in
      print("my timer: Fired \(Date.now.mediumTimeLocalizedDescription)")
   }
   myTimer!.fire()
}
```

I get the following output:

```
my timer: Fired 14:27:14
my timer: Fired 14:27:17
my timer: invalidating 14:27:17
my timer: Fired 14:27:17
my timer: Fired 14:27:27
```

Expected output:

```
my timer: Fired 14:27:14
my timer: Fired 14:27:17
my timer: invalidating 14:27:17
my timer: Fired 14:27:27
```

As you can see when I invalidate the timer fires right away!

Is there any way to prevent that?

I looked Apple documentation and it states "Stops the timer from ever firing again and requests its removal from its run loop." which I interpret as "When you invalidate, the timer does not fire anymore". Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call startMyTimer() again in DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter completion. In this function you initialize timer.

Comment: If you look at the timestamps it fires at second 17 twice.
What I want is it to fire at second 17 once and then from second 27 again every 10 seconds. Instead it fires once when i call it and once when I invalidate.

Comment: Let me clarify it.
`my timer: Fired 14:27:14 -> startMyTimer() fire action
my timer: Fired 14:27:17 -> asyncAfter fire action
my timer: invalidating 14:27:17 asyncAfter invalidate action
my timer: Fired 14:27:17 -> async after called startMyTimer(), fire action
my timer: Fired 14:27:27 -> Scheduled action`

Comment: Oh... I don't know how I let that slip! Thank you very much!